# Difference between "ESRI" and "OGC" validity

Tags: python, arcpy, geopandas, shapely

When I use the `Check Geometry` tool in ArcGIS Pro, it asks whether I want to validate using ESRI or OGC methods. What is the difference between these two methods?

### edit

I originally asked a second question in this post but it was too far off the first one.

Second question now here: [Check for ESRI geometry validity using shapely or similar](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/468669/check-for-esri-geometry-validity-using-shapely-or-similar)

Comment: @SonofaBeach fair enough. Opened a new question here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/468669/check-for-esri-geometry-validity-using-shapely-or-similar

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Check Geometry tool's help page](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/data-management/check-geometry.htm)...

> The Esri validation option ensures that geometry is topologically
> correct using the [Esri Simplify method](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcobjects/latest/net/webframe.htm#itopologicaloperator_simplify.htm). Only the Esri validation
> is available for data stored in an enterprise geodatabase.
>
> The Open Geospatial Consortium (OGC) validation method ensures that
> geometry complies with the OGC specification as defined in [OpenGIS
> Implementation Standard for Geographic information – simple feature
> access – Part 1: common architecture](https://portal.opengeospatial.org/files/?artifact_id=25355).

For more details on what the differences actually are, click on those links.

Comment: The banana polygon is what user meets most often https://postgis.net/workshops/postgis-intro/validity.html. And a single two-part hole that touches itself is the ESRI way https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/using-sql-with-gdbs/geometry-validation.htm but an error for OGC.

Comment: As a hole, that would be an inversion. It's inversions which are the difference, and plain vanilla inversions are way more common (especially in raster-to-vector conversions).