# Check for ESRI geometry validity using shapely or similar

Tags: python, arcpy, geopandas, shapely

I have a `geopandas` dataframe in Python. Is there a way to check geometry validity under the ESRI scheme as opposed to the OGC spec using `shapely`/`geopandas`/some hacky way, or am I constrained to using `arcpy`?

Comment: Just guessing, but I suspect that it's unlikely anyone other than ESRI have implemented the ESRI way in a widely available standard library.  Of course, you can always implement the ESRI way yourself, but that would be a lot of work.  So technincally, the answer is "yes" (implement it yourself), but practically, I'm guessing that answer is "no".

Comment: The main difference is in the way inversions are handled. If something is OGC clean, ArcPy can "fix" it as necessary.

Comment: What about GDAL/OGR?  Maybe this post will help?  https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/204141/how-to-to-validate-geometries-using-ogr2ogr

Comment: @GBG ideally in python but I'll consider `ogr` and take a look at the question.

Comment: @jesnes there is a GDAL/OGR Python library at PyPI so no need to do a GDAL installation and run command line GDAL statements.  See here:  https://pypi.org/project/GDAL/